# Is it possible to retrieve shader function names associated with a technique pass using the DirectX Effect API?

Tags: shaders, directx, hlsl

For example, given the pass

```
pass p0
{
    SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VSFunction()))
    SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PSFunction()))
}
```

Ss it possible to retrieve the names VSFunction and PSFunction? It doesn't look like any of the associated shader descriptors actually contain the name of the entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an HLSL effect is compiled, the entry point names don't show up anywhere in the bytecode (you can check it yourself using fxc.exe and a hex editor).  Since the bytecode is the input to the Effect API, I don't believe there's any way to extract the entry point names.

The entry point names do appear in the debug information (which is included in the bytecode if you ask for it with a compiler flag).  If the shader was compiled with debug information, it can be extracted using [D3DGetDebugInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607328.aspx), but as far as I know, the format of this information is undocumented.